# python: checking for errors in the users input

Tags: python-2.7

I would like
to check if a string can be a ﬂoat before I attempt to convert it to a ﬂoat. This way, if the
string is not ﬂoat, we can print an error message and exit instead of crashing the
program.
so when the user inputs something, I wanna see if its  a float so it will print "true" if its not then it will print"false" rather than crashing. I don't want to use built in functions for this. I need to make my own function for this.

I tried :
import types

```
def isFloat():
    x = raw_input("Enter: ")
    if(x) == float:
        print("true")

    if(x) == str:
        print("false")

isFloat()
```

I don't know if its true or not but it wont work it wont print anything either

Answer (score 0):

The recommended thing to do here is to `try` it:

```
try:
    f = float(x)
    print("true")
except ValueError:
    # handle error here
    print("false")
```

This underscores the Python philosophy *"It's better to ask for forgiveness than for permission"*.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to figure out whether a string represents a float is to try to convert it. You could check first and convert then, but why should you? You'd do it twice, without need.

Consider this code:

```
def read_float():
    """
    return a floating-point number, or None
    """
    while True:
        s = raw_input('Enter a float: ').strip()
        if not s:
            return None
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print 'Not a valid number: %r' % s

num = read_float()
while num is not None:
    ... do something ...
    print 'Try again?'
    num = read_float()
```